# Trying to make a google maps chart that shows different markers, but i have an un-kown syntax error

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to make a map that shows different makers using lat&long. cords but I was confused on the documentation of google chart maps. So i must've made a mistake I cannot find could anyone help?
Well here's my code:

```js
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['map']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

    function drawMap () {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Address');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Marker')

      data.addRows([
          [41.0398, -73.6122, 'Greenwich High School','pink'],
          [41.020743,-73.635352, "Boxcar Cantina", 'blue'],
          [41.041831,-73.583571,"El Charrito", 'blue'],
          [41.036406,-73.603838,'Tomatillo Taco Joint', 'blue'],
          [41.055813,-73.525459,'Casa Villa','green'],
          [41.106564,-73.548439,'Ole Mole','green'],
          [41.054949,-73.540833,'Bartaco Stamford','green'],
          [41.056176,-73.538188,'Cantina Tequila Bar & Southwest Grill','green'],
          [41.056422,-73.538863,'Picante! Fresh Mexican Grill','green']
   ]);

      var url = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-map-markers/48/';

      var options = {
        zoomLevel: 6,
        showTip: true,
        useMapTypeControl: true,
        icons: {
          blue: {
            normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Azure-icon.png',
            selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Right-Azure-icon.png'
          },
          green: {
            normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Push-Pin-1-Chartreuse-icon.png',
            selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Push-Pin-1-Right-Chartreuse-icon.png'
          },
          pink: {
            normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Pink-icon.png',
            selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Right-Pink-icon.png'
          }
        }
      };
      var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));

      map.draw(data, options);
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map_div" style="height: 500px; width: 900px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Map Chart displays a map using the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/). Data values are displayed as markers on the map. Data values can be coordinates (lat-long pairs) or addresses. The map will be scaled so that it includes all the identified points.

The `syntax error` means that a character or string incorrectly placed in a command or instruction that causes a failure in execution.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['map'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

function drawMap() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Country', 'Population'],
['China', 'China: 1,363,800,000'],
['India', 'India: 1,242,620,000'],
['US', 'US: 317,842,000'],
['Indonesia', 'Indonesia: 247,424,598'],
['Brazil', 'Brazil: 201,032,714'],
['Pakistan', 'Pakistan: 186,134,000'],
['Nigeria', 'Nigeria: 173,615,000'],
['Bangladesh', 'Bangladesh: 152,518,015'],
['Russia', 'Russia: 146,019,512'],
['Japan', 'Japan: 127,120,000']
]);

var options = { showTip: true };

var map = new  google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

map.draw(data, options);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want your maps to be line drawings rather than satellite imagery, use a [geochart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) instead.